# Configure Vue to have a development and a production build

Tags: vue.js

I inherited a Vue project that only builds production builds and uglifies everything. It doesn't have a webpack.config.js like I'm used to, it only has a vue.config.js file. When I do `npm run build` it builds a production. The build command is `"build": "vue-cli-service build"` and I don't see a way to do something like `--mode=development`.

I tried adding a webpack.config.js file which built, but at the same time broke the webpage, because it no longer built the same.

Here is my vue.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    lintOnSave: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
    configureWebpack: {
        entry: './src/main.js',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /libs\.js$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'script-loader'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /angLibs\.js$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'script-loader'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /welcome\.js$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'script-loader'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /app\.js$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'script-loader'
                    }
                }
            ]

        },
        output: {
            publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API + '/',
            chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/App/i18n/*.*'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'), force: true }
            ], { copyUnmodified: true, context: 'static/' }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/Content/*/*.*'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'), force: true }
            ], { copyUnmodified: true, context: 'static/' }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/fonts/*.*'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'), force: true }
            ], { copyUnmodified: true, context: 'static/' }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/react/*.*'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'), force: true }
            ], { copyUnmodified: true, context: 'static/' })
        ]
    }
};
```

I would like to have a development build that is quicker and is not uglified/minified (or retains the map files of files it includes in the webpack).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a Vue CLI v3 build. For a webpack dev-server with hot-reload, use `npm run serve`.

Otherwise, you can build in `development` mode via

```sh
npx vue-cli-service build --mode development
```

or, if you don't have `npx`

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service build --mode development
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

---

Another option is to add a new script to `package.json`, eg

```js
"buildDev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development"
```

and run

```sh
npm run buildDev
```

---

For configuring Webpack, see https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html.

For example

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // config goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize I could just pass through arguments to webpack here. Sure enough, the basic development and production build flags pass right through.